# Varnish: Sending "If-None-Match"-Header to Backends?

Tags: load-balancing, varnish, cache

I'd like to use etag caching directly in my application / verify the eTag in my Application.
How is it possible to route the "If-None-Match" header to the backends?
It seems that Varnish is cutting out this header by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved it:
Varnish does not remove the If-None-Match header.
It was just my web app delivered from cache while requests were still coming in.
Chrome served the old version of the page. COUGH. COUGH. COUGH.

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194946/271351), and my experience, seem to contradict this statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it to a different header that varnish doesn't know about, and then read that header in your backend instead.

At the top of vcl_recv, try:

```
set req.http.X-If-None-Match-Previously = req.http.If-None-Match;
```

and then read the X-If-None-Match-Previously header in your application.

I'm not sure how that's going to interact with your caching but that will pass the header data through if Varnish is stripping it from its backend requests.

Comment: Are you sure that it should work?
I'm sending the headers but the app does not receive anything.

even

  set req.http.X-If-None-Match-Previously = "test";

does not work.

Comment: Any ideas? Seems not to be possible to add various headers?

Comment: Definitely possible. Is there something between varnish and your app that might be stripping them?

Comment: Okay, may fault:   set req.http.X-If-None-Match-Previously = "foo" works now. But it seems that req.http.If-None-Match was stripped before by Varnish :-( Any Ideas on this? Inline C?

Comment: Stupid me, see the real solution below.

Comment: This yields a compile error with Varnish 6: `Cannot be set in method 'vcl_backend_response' Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2`